# How to remove decorative sleeve from PVC pipe?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc

I'm trying to remove a decorative bronze (not sure if that's the right material) sleeve that's over a PVC drain.  I can turn it a little but I'm not having any luck pulling it off.  I have concerns about trying to carefully cut it off, not sure if I will damage the PVC underneath.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would try a couple things:

- Tap a tool like a small flat-blade screwdriver or awl in from the end to try and separate the metal at several points.
- Put a little heat on it. Hit it with a hair dryer until it's just hot to the touch. It might expand and soften a bit.
- Tap on the metal from the end to try and jar it loose.
- Use an abrasive wheel in a rotary tool (Dremel) to carefully score the metal lengthwise so it can be split as in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Pry the collar that's up against the wall away from the wall (could be a set screw at the bottom) and remove it. Look for some sort of binding screw that's holding the sleeve in place. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how those can be separated without damaging the PVC pipe.

Dremel tool will not work because its handheld and you cannot control the depth.

Inserting a screwdriver and trying to separate will only damage the PVC pipe because it is softer than the metal pipe and does not provides support for the screwdriver.

Since the PVC pipe already has quite deposits inside it needs to be replaced anyway.

Heating might help because the metal part will expand become more loose while the PVC pipe will not expand as much, thus providing a opportunity to use pliers and twist it off.

Either of these methods is more time-consuming than just replacing the PVC pipe.

Comment: Dremel tool CAN cut without going deep if you have steady hands. Many users don't, though. And I don't have any strong opinion on whether it would be useful here.